# How to mix 2 columns with data in one with NULLS involved QGIS

Tags: multiple-columns, qgis

I have 2 columns filled with different numbers, and I'd like to make a third column relocating the numbers that get repeated. There can also be a NULL in these columns, in that case I'd like to get the other result.

Here's an example.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | NULL |
| NULL | 4 |
| NULL | NULL |

I's like to join both columns in one (Column C) with the following rules.

Value A != Value B --> A string of characters looking like  this '???'

Value A == Value B --> Get Value A or B, doesn't matter

Value A AND Value B  = NULL --> Get Value A

Value A = NULL AND Value B --> Get Value B

Value A and B == NULL --> Get NULL

With this result, everything works fine except the first case shown before, where Column A has X value and Column B has Y value. I can't get the expected '???' result that I want.

Haven't tried using arrays.

[image: My code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is better to post code as text than as a screenshot of code editor. Otherwise it is a valid question.

Comment: What are the types of the fields "PUNTS INICIALS ed50_EQM1 C d" and "PUNTS FINALS ed50_EQM1 C d" as well as the new field (Column C)?

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the Field Calculator to compute the values for Column C from the values of Column A and Column B.

Note that QGIS Feature attributes have types they could be either integer, float, or text. Assuming your Column A and Column B are integers, then Column C would also be an integer column, therefore the value `'???'` would not be acceptable as this cannot be converted to an integer value.

One common approach to this is to reserve a specific value from the integer range as an additional INVALID DATA value. For instance if all your valid values are positive you could use `-1` as your INVALID DATA value.

Then your code could look like this:

```
if( ("PUNTS INICIALS ed50_EQM1 C d" is NULL) or ("PUNTS FINALS ed50_EQM1 C d" is NULL),
    coalesce("PUNTS INICIALS ed50_EQM1 C d","PUNTS FINALS ed50_EQM1 C d"),
    if("PUNTS INICIALS ed50_EQM1 C d"="PUNTS FINALS ed50_EQM1 C d","PUNTS INICIALS ed50_EQM1 C d",-1))
```

Note that `coalesce()` can be used to handle the case when one of the values is NULL.